# Which performance is best (Table type or XML) to Pass as Parameter in to SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to pass data into a sql function which resides on another db. Data is more than 10000 at a time. So what is the best practice/performance for passing data into sql function.

1. BY XML
2. By Table Type.

Please advise me as it's urgent.I need best performance. If possible please give me benchmark or example also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can do it by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table-valued parameters are usually faster, mainly because there is no need to unpack them on the server side. Make sure you also take into account the time to pack the data client-side.

Here's a lent to an article providing comparison of various methods of sending data to SQL Server:

http://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-perftest-2009.html